# Selenium c# - waiting for text not to be visible but doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, selenium, assert

I am new to Selenium and C# and creating an automated test whereby I create something and delete it straightaway (all in the same test).

The last step in my test is to verify the name of the item I've deleted is no longer visible - this is where I seem to be getting stuck.

I am in a modal dialog and the item is visible in the background, so once I confirm the deletion in the modal dialog, the next step is to verify the item name is no longer visible, but the code does see the name and therefore throws an exception because it is true instead of my expected result of false.

See below the code I'm using:

```
public bool DeletedCategoryNoLongerVisible(string CategoryDisplayName) {
  try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='10_anchor']")));
    Driver.FindElement(By.XPath($ "//*[@class='jstree-anchor'][text()='{CategoryDisplayName}']"));
    return false;
  } catch (Exception) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You trying to verify the element or the text?  Is the element actually deleted or is it just the text?

Comment: @IamBatman, the text has deleted so I'm wanting to verify that. The ElementToBeClickable i've specified is a button which is behind the modal but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: So it's the text on a button or in an input field?  Either way, why don't you grab the text from the element and do a conditional?  If doesn't exist, do this, else do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for the targeted element to be missing or for its displayed text to be empty with `InvisibilityOfElementWithText`:

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
  .Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementWithText(By.XPath(...), CategoryDisplayName));
```

And if the element is hidden with another element on top of it, then try to click it until failure:

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
  .Until((driver) => {
    try {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(...)).Click();
        return false;
    } catch (WebDriverException) { 
        return true;
    }
  });
```